# Select Count take too long to be executed

Tags: sql, count

I'm executing two queries. One that return the number of records and one that display the results. But how come the query that return the total of records takes 11 sec to be excecuted while the one displaying the result take less than 1 sec to be executed ? It should be the opposite, no ?

**SQL that return the total of records is executed after 11 sec**

```
(SELECT count(*) as id
      FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT title, version
      FROM book AS b
      WHERE b.title IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user AS u WHERE u.column1 = b.column1)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DISTINCT title, version
      FROM book2 AS b2
      WHERE b.title IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user AS u WHERE u.column2 = b.column1)
    ) c )
```

**SQL that display the result is executed in less than 1 sec**

```
   SELECT DISTINCT title, version
   FROM book AS b
   WHERE b.title IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user AS u WHERE u.column1 = b.column1)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DISTINCT title, version
   FROM book2 AS b2
   WHERE b.title IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user AS u WHERE u.column2 = b.column1)
```

Comment: Your query doesn't really make sense.  You want to count a book twice if it meets both conditions?

Comment: What i want in the query is not important. It just and example of a query. Cause why the count is taking more time to be executed than the one fetching and displaying the rows

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products optimize in different ways.)

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing apples and oranges.  The `count(*)` version has to process *all* the data before it can return anything.

The more detailed version can start returning rows as they become available -- which is presumably when the first subquery starts returning rows.

I don't think either of these queries are what you really need, but this question does not provide that information.

Also, are `book` and `version` *not* unique?  I wonder if this does what you want:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM book b
  WHERE b.title IS NOT NULL AND
        ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user u WHERE u.column1 = b.column1) OR
          EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user u WHERE u.column2 = b.column1)
        );
```

You can also use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.title + ':' + b.version)
. . .
```

Comment: I even removed the second query with the UNION ALL and it takes me the same time ! The problem then is with the distinct !  Why when i remove the count(*) the query is executed in less than 1 sec ?

Comment: @Kivo . . . It is the same reason.  The `COUNT(*)` has to generate all the rows in the result set before it can return anything.  The detailed form can return rows as they are generated so you are seeing the time-to-first row.  Of course, there could be other issues with different execution plans, but this is the more common explanation.

Comment: The goal to have a separate query for returning the records is to be executed faster than the one fetching datas row by row....

Comment: @Kivo . . . Your last comment doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT title, version
FROM book b
LEFT JOIN u ON b.column1 = u.column2
LEFT JOIN u2 ON b.column1 = u2.column1
WHERE u2.column1 IS NULL
AND b.title IS NOT NULL
) sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are chances that you can improve your query here is one of the example and you can check other as well shared by friends

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM book AS b
LEFT OUTER JOIN User U ON u.Column1 = b.column1
LEFT OUTER JOIN user u1 ON u1.Column2 = b.column1
WHERE b.title IS NOT NULL 
AND u.Id IS NULL -- with assumption u might have another column id
AND u1.Id IS NULL -- with assumption u1 might have aother column or
GROUP BY title,Version
```

Comment: Why removing the UNION ALL ? the left outer join doesnt give me what i expect

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT **count(title)** as id
      FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT title, version
      FROM book AS b
      WHERE b.title IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user AS u WHERE u.column1 = b.column1)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DISTINCT title, version
      FROM book2 AS b2
      WHERE b.title IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user AS u WHERE u.column2 = b.column1)
    ) c )
```

"*" is never advisable as it accounts for all unnecessary details too.